# Reuse Workflow in github action - Azure deployment

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service, github-actions

I need to reuse a workflow in another workflow instead of repeating things.

The `build` workflow already performs `pip install` and I just need the installed package to be reused during the `deploy` workflow instead of re-running `pip install`

```
     build:
       runs-on: ubuntu-latest
       needs: create-envfile
       steps:
          - uses: actions/checkout@v2
          - name: Set up Python version
            uses: actions/setup-python@v1
            with:
              python-version: '3.8'
          - name: Create and start virtual environment
            run: |
               python -m venv venv
               source venv/bin/activate
  
          - name: Install dependencies
             run: |
               eval `ssh-agent -s`
               cat ./.github/workflows/id_rsa | ssh-add -
               pip install -r requirements.txt

          - name: Upload artifact for deployment jobs
            uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
            with:
             name: python-app
             path: |
                . 
                !venv/

    deploy:
       runs-on: ubuntu-latest
       needs: build
       environment:
           name: 'Production'
           url: ${{ steps.somesecret }}

       steps:
          - name: Download artifact from build job
            uses: actions/download-artifact@v2
            with:
               name: python-app
               path: .
    
         - name: 'Deploy to Azure Web App'
             uses: azure/webapps-deploy@v2
             id: deploy-to-webapp
             with:
               app-name: 'project-prod'
               slot-name: 'Production'
               publish-profile: ${{ secrets.somesecrethere }}
```

What happens here, is as long as the `deploy` workflow  finishes downloading artifacts from `build`, it will restart running `pip install` the packages from requirements.txt, which of course a redundant. How to prevent this and reuse the already installed package instead